# CSS class ignored in list

Tags: html, css

This produces the correct result:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#red_box {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

  <div id ="container">
      <div id="red_box">a</div>
      <div id="blu_box">b</div>
  </div>
```

When I move the height property into its own class and give the element both styles, the height is ignored.

```
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#box {
  height: 30%
}
#red_box {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

  <div id ="container">
      <div class="box red_box">a</div>
      <div class="box blu_box">b</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You don't have any class selectors.

Comment: They are `class` and not `id`. You are using the `id` selectors (with `#` prefix) instead of class selectors.

Comment: `#red_box` is for id, not classes. `.red_box` is.

Answer (score 4):

change the # sign to . sign for box and red_box css selectors because you are using class, # is used for id's and id should be unique whereas more than one element can have the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You got a few of problems in your code:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.box { /* Change id selector "#" to class selector "." */
  height: 30%
}

.red_box { /* Change id selector "#" to class selector "." */
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div id="container"> <!-- Remove space between id and equal sign -->
      <div class="box red_box">a</div>
      <div class="box blu_box">b</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CSS classes over ID's, but at the very least you need to be consitent. The issue comes from you using #box and #red_box which is for id's but you reference them as classes.

see correct code using classes below

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  height: 30%
}
.red_box {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

  <div class="container">
      <div class="box red_box">a</div>
      <div class="box blu_box">b</div>
  </div>
```